# ZLIB.h header file implementation

Tags: zlib

I want to know about the zlib.h open source header file implementation.

I want to know what exactly the statement below means:

```
`Z_VERSION_ERROR` if the zlib library version (zlib_version) is incompatible
with the version assumed by the caller (`ZLIB_VERSION`).
```

I am working on an ARM arch64 platform machine and using this open source header in our build. It is returning `Z_VERSION_ERROR`.

I am trying to build an executable called 'denzip' using the library libenz.a, which I created with the zlib source.

**PS:** 'libdenz.a' is a library which I created from the standard library 'libz.a', from the zlib source. The reason is that we have a requirement to rename some symbols in original library (libz.a).

Build command:

```
common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0/bin/gcc -L/usr/X11R6/lib -O2 -DUSE_FLEX -Wall -Wno-char-subscripts -fPIC -DLINUX -DG_DISABLE_CONST_RETURNS -fno-strict-aliasing -o Release/tools/denzip -Wl,-E Release/tools/denzip.o -L/home/clib/extlibs/Lnx/lib -ldenbase -ldenz -ldenbase -ldl -lm -lc
```

I have the library 'libdenz.a' is at path '/home/clib/extlibs/Lnx/lib'.
After executable 'denzip' is created. When I try to use that executable I get:

```
denzip -c trctotb.tcl
 Error: *** Error: Error in trctotb.tcl compression: bad library version
 *** Error: trctotb.tcl: aborting compression
```

Source:

```
int rc;
rc = DenZ_deflateInit( &zstream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION );
switch ( rc ) {
case Z_MEM_ERROR:
reportZError( "insufficient memory", contentType,
              "compression", &zstream );
return FALSE;
case Z_VERSION_ERROR:
printf("The integer is %d\n", zlib_version);
reportZError( "bad library version", contentType,
              "compression", &zstream );
return FALSE;
}
```

`Z_VERSION_ERROR` is coming from zlib.h

Comment: It means your header file does not correspond to the library you are linking.

Comment: @rici,thanks for your reply... I verified that library 'libz.a' which is coming from ZLIB source. And zlib.h header file is off same version 1.2.7, Still facing the same issue. Do I need verify anything else other than this?  Step1) I verified that header has '#define ZLIB_VERSION "1.2.7"' Steap 2 ) I am using the same library which I created from ZLIB1.2.7 source.

Comment: how did you verify that you are actually using the library you just compiled? At a minimum, edit your question to include the actual build steps for the executable which reports the error.

Comment: @rici, I verified by checking the version of that library. 'grep '1/.2/.7 libz.a'' Command shows the output. And the header file which I am using has the macro defined with version 1.2.7, I am editing question for you.

Comment: That verifies the version in the library you created but it does not verify that your executable was linked with that library.

Comment: @rici, how can we verify whether the library is linked to our executable? Any command for that ?

Comment: With dynamic libraries you can easily check with `ldd` but static linking is a bit more complicated. `readelf` will provide some useful options information. The edits to your question are useful; that may make it easier to answer.

Comment: @rici,i verified that my executable has the functions which are defined the library 'libdenz.a'. It means that it is linked with that library right?

Comment: Yes, I would think so. So it could be that you did something wrong when you modified the source code.

Comment: @rici, I did not touch any source code. I am just renaming the symbols from standard library 'lbz.a' and using it in our build on ARM platform.

Comment: deflateInit is a macro; you can't rename it without modifying zlib.h, which is part of the source code.

Comment: @rici, its not a macro it is a subroutine :- ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT deflateInit OF((z_streamp strm, int level));

Comment: and where did you find its definition, pray tell? Look further down in zlib.h: `/* deflateInit and inflateInit are macros to allow checking the zlib version
 * and the compiler's view of z_stream:
 */`

Comment: @rici, got it... now what needs to be modify in zlib.h to resolve this?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what you did exactly. But I'd say that you need to ask a different question.

Comment: @rici, one thing I noticed on my code (snippet above) 'rc' variable is declared as 'int'. But, in switch statement it has characters like case Z_VERSION_ERROR .... etc , how does it works?

Comment: It's a macro defined in zlib.h: `#define Z_VERSION_ERROR (-6)`

Comment: @rici, Thanks...

Comment: @rici, I closely check the source files..i closely check all the source files and found that deflate.c is returning 'Z_VERSION_ERROR' by checking below conditions : - if (version == Z_NULL || version[0] != my_version[0] ||
        stream_size != sizeof(z_stream)) {
        return Z_VERSION_ERROR;
    }                                                                                                                   I just want to hack the code...Can you please tell me what exactly zstream condition is for ?

Comment: It checks that the size of the `z_stream` structure defined when the library function was compiled is the same as the size of that structure passed into the call. Since the argument comes from the calling function, it will be the size in the header when the calling function was compiled. So it's another verification that the library and the header file used by the caller come from the same zlib version.

Comment: Really, SO comment threads are not really intended to provide tutorial services. What you should do is write a new question of the form "I want to do X" (i.e., your real task -- create a version of zlib whose external interfaces have different names, or even some higher level goal -- and add "I tried this (referencing this question) but it doesn't seem to be correct approach because it resulted in a version error." That will let people help with your higher-level goal instead of following you down the rabbit hole."

Answer (score 0):

It means that the header files zlib.h and zconf.h are from a different version of zlib than the libz.so or libz.a library binary that you are linking to.

Print `ZLIB_VERSION` and the result of `zlibVersion()` to see the versions of the header and library respectively.

Comment: I verified that version in /usr/include/zlib.h & my local directories where I have header files 'zconf.h' & 'zlib.h' and library 'libdenz.a' has the same version 1.2.7

Comment: Where do I need to add the print statements to print 'ZLIB_VERSION' , zlibVersion() ? can you please tell me?

Comment: Anywhere. Put it at the beginning of the main routine in your build, and then exit. See what it says when you run it.